# How to use variable names inside literals in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Is it possible to write e.g. a Vector literal which uses a variable inside so that the variable gets evaluated correctly and the resulting Vector doesn't just contain the name/symbol of the variable?

For example:

```
(setq inner ["d" "e"])
["a" "b" inner]
```

Results into:

```
["a" "b" inner]
```

But what I would want is:

["a" "b" ["d" "e"]]

I've done some Clojure coding before Elisp, there it works as I expected:

```
(def inner ["d" "e"])
user=> ["a" "b" inner]             
["a" "b" ["d" "e"]]
```

What's the fundamental thing I don't understand about Elisp here? I can of course work around this, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 13):

When using the vector syntax, the elements are considered constant. From the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual 6.4:

> A vector, like a string or a number, is considered a constant for
>   evaluation: the result of evaluating it is the same vector.  This does
>   not evaluate or even examine the elements of the vector.

On the other hand, you could use the `vector` function to create a vector where the elements are evaluated:

```
(setq inner ["d" "e"])
(vector "a" "b" inner)
=> ["a" "b" ["d" "e"]]
```

Answer (score 8):

use backquote literal. It's possible to use as same as for list.

```
(setq inner ["d" "e"])
`["a" "b" ,inner]
=> ["a" "b" ["d" "e"]]
```